# C++ - Overriding Virtual Templated Member Functions

Tags: c++, templates

In this example:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int i);
};

template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<T> createObj()
    {
        return std::make_unique<T>();
    }
};

class Derived  : public Base<MyClass>
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> createObj() override
    {
        return std::make_unique<MyClass>(4);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Derived instance;
    auto createdObj = instance.createObj();
}
```

I cannot call the derived createObj() function. It seems the code is trying to still call the base version with the MyClass instance which leads to compilation failures since the required construction arguments are not passed. Why does this not work as a normal overriden function and call the derived version that does supply the correct arguments?

Comment: What makes you think `"...the code is trying to still call the base version..."`?  Even if it's not called the base class implementation of  `createObj` must still compile.

Comment: @G.M. The base class tries to call `std::make_unique<MyClass>()` which does not give it the required construction argument.

Comment: @WaleyM your code is not trying to call it, nevertheless the method must be valid

Comment: Ok great thanks, I thought I could override that function to make the templated class work with MyClass but apparently not.

Comment: the issue isnt really related to templates. If you write a base class that has an invalid method `foo` then that class is broken even though you never use it directly but only as base class and all derived classes override the method and you never call the method.

Comment: you can specialize `Base` to make it work with `MyClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misinterpreted the error. The [error message is](https://godbolt.org/z/5hr95bfxh):

```
In file included from <source>:1:
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../include/c++/10.3.0/memory:83:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../include/c++/10.3.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:962:34: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'MyClass'
    { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
                                 ^
<source>:15:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::make_unique<MyClass>' requested here
        return std::make_unique<T>();
                    ^
<source>:19:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'Base<MyClass>::createObj' requested here
class Derived  : public Base<MyClass>
      ^
<source>:6:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'i', but no arguments were provided
    MyClass(int i);
    ^
<source>:3:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
class MyClass
      ^
<source>:3:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
1 error generated.
```

`Base<MyClass>` tries to default construct a `MyClass` but `MyClass` has no default constuctor. Even if you are not trying to call `Base<MyClass>::createObj` the method must be valid because it is instantiated as part of `Base<MyClass>`.

In other words, merely instantiating `Base<MyClass>` will fail. Not calling the method does not make it less of an error.

I am not entirely sure whats the aim, but if you make the method pure virtual in `Base` your code [compiles without issues](https://godbolt.org/z/qeTEGvGfs):

```
#include <memory>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int i) {}
};

template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<T> createObj() = 0;
};

class Derived  : public Base<MyClass>
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> createObj() override
    {
        return std::make_unique<MyClass>(4);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Derived instance;
    auto createdObj = instance.createObj();
}
```

Alternatively you could provide a default contructor for `MyClass`.